# Could I improve this django model structure?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am attempting to make an expense reporting website.  I incur expenses at work which I report in an excel spreadsheet sent via email attachment.  Each spreadsheet can include up to 15 expenses.  The ideal website would accept user information (for populating the areas of the spreadsheet that don't change, their expenses, export the user inputs into a spreadsheet, attach a receipt photo and send as an email attachment.  I'm aware there are apps that do this, but I've chosen this as my project to continue learning Python, web development and give me something useful (if I can make it, which is feeling unlikely right now).

I've gone through the MDN Django tutorial (local library).  My focus now is on the models.  I am using Django and would be grateful for feedback regarding my initial model structure.    I feel like my model structure should be simpler than I'm making it, but I don't know how to reduce it.  Specifically, I'm wondering if I need to have a separate model for each expense and a model for the report as a whole.  Or can I just have a report model including the fields that I currently have in the expense model?

Any advice, criticism or vicious personal attacks?  Is there a better way to do this?  Thank you in advance.
[image: model first draft]

Comment: If a user has a relationship with a report and the report has a relationship with expenses, you don't really need a relationship between user and expense as it can be derived via report.

Comment: Thank you for replying.  To help me further understand; the relationship isn't needed, but does that mean the expense model isn't needed?  Is there any utility in having an expense model?  I think the answer is no, but I'm not confident.

Comment: Thinking more about this, I feel like I've answered my own question.  I can call the model.fields as needed in my application which leads me to think there isn't really a reason to have an expense model.  Instead, include those fields in the report model.  If anyone has a dissenting opinion I'd be glad to hear it.

Comment: If a report can have multiple expenses you'll need a model for it, can't keep adding expense_1 expense_2... Expense_n fields to the report model, that won't scale

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up @Roy Zwambag.  I think this project exceeds my capability right now, going to find something simpler to keep moving forward.